# Large browser parsing time after loading CSS's and JS's

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, web-frontend

I'm trying to decrease page loading time of a project I'm working on. At first the team I'm working with tried to optimize Apache/Symfony2/Postge but finaly in Networking panel of Chrome's Dev Tools I've found a large "gap" after loading all css and js files. The "gap" disappears when script files are removed. If I leave only jquery.min.js (no other libraries or scripts loaded) page still loads for aprox. 1.5s.

Developer tools doesn't say what happens during this period. I think this might be when browser parses and interprets CSS and JS but I need decreasing of DOMContentLoaded time. Any suggestions?

*This is my first post and I need 10 reputation to post images, so I've uploaded screenshot of what I'm talking about here:*

http://tinypic.com/m/imqw0n/1

**P.S.:** Screenshot is taken on "average" PC. The same test on my personal laptop (AsusG750JZ, 8-core CPU, 16Gb RAM, nVIDA 880m) shows very different results - load time is about 1.5s instead of 5.2s. Unfortunately I can't make everyone use the web app on hi-end ;)

**P.S.2:** Async loading of JS is not an option. I've tried RequireJS but I didn't like the results. It was clumsy because of all scripts dependencies.

Comment: Do you have a video in your page? Something like youtube or others? In my experience that can cause long waiting times

Comment: No, it's an administration application and this long wait is present even on the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

In DevTools, go to the 'Timeline' tab. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline